# для чего нам OpenGL в таком виде?

Tags: opengl, gui

мучает вопрос, какой смысл в именно такой вот спецификации как OpenGl которой пользуются наверно почти все UI-фреймворки где нет возможности задать отрисовку нативных контролов средствами ОС? почему все рисуют их сами, задавая все до мелочей, а именно анимация при наведении на контрол, цвет выделения текста (который еще меняется с настройками в операционке), подстройка под тему ОС? Логичнее было бы имхо для кроссплатформенности придумать стандарт рисования 2d/3d графики и в комплекте каких то часто используемых базовых контролов, или я что то путаю и все работает вообще иначе?

Comment: Может вся проблема в том как вы готовите OpenGL и для чего его используете?

Comment: OpenGL, как я понимаю, для немного другой цели создавался. Он для более низкоуровневой графики, чем готовые контролы. *"почему все рисуют их сами, задавая все до мелочей"* Чтобы на всех платформах гуи выглядел полностью одинаково? И вообще, "все" - это кто? Есть, например, wxWidgets, который делает гуи из нативных контролов.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну я написал "наверно почти все", ясно что Tk тоже умеет операционкой кнопочки рисовать, но он далеко не так распространен как основанные на OpenGL либы. А по поводу вопроса "Чтобы на всех платформах гуи выглядел полностью одинаково?", он же в том то и дело что не выглядит одинаково, qt для каждой платформы по своему рисует, swing тоже в яве криво, но похоже рисует, т.е. дело не в этом по идее. Забыл еще упомянуть такой момент к этому что вкладки меню ("файл, Изменить, Справка...") мы не рисуем же, мало того на маке и ubuntu unity мы этого просто не сможем сделать

Comment: OpenGL — это низкоуровневый API для рисования, а не средство построения интерфейсов, вот и всё. Для интерфейсов есть этот ваш Qt, который, насколько я помню, умеет рисовать себя в том числе с помощью OpenGL

Comment: @andreymal спасибо! но вопрос, что в нем такого низкоуровневого и для чего? только скорость или еще какие то преследуются цели?

Comment: @Ljachowsky для универсального API доступа к ресурсам видеокарты, не зависящего от конкретной её модели, и для скорости

Comment: @Ljachowsky - конечно. Одно дело нагружать ЦП и RAM компьютера, другое дело работать напрямую с процессором видеокарты и ее оперативной памятью GDDR. Это разгружает ЦП и другие ресурсы - раз, увеличивает скорость обработки графики в десятки и сотни раз - два.